# How to automatically add page 2/2 in html print page pdf

Tags: html, css, laravel

How to automatically add page 2/2 to in my HTML print page, every-time the page 1 ends the second page will follow. Right now with my code only page 1 working

Here is my CSS

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
  font-family: "Times New Roman"; /* replace this with your font */
}
page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
 
 
}

@media print {
  body, page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;

  }
}
```

This is my view

```
<page size="A4" >@foreach($scores as $key => $score)<table><tr><th>Subject</th><th>Teacher</th><th>MTA</th></tr>@foreach($score as $row)<tr><td>&nbsp;{{ $row->subject->subject_name}}</td><td>&nbsp;{{ $row->subject->user->name}}</td><td>&nbsp;{{ $row->term1_ma}}</td></tr>@endforeach </table>@endforeach </page>
```

Comment: maybe its worth to take a look on css `page-break` properties, e.g. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/

Comment: how to break i'm using loop is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css, you can use content: counter(page);

```
 @page {
   @bottom-left {
        content: counter(page) "/" counter(pages);
    }
 }
```

Refrence:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters

http://www.princexml.com/doc/9.0/page-numbers/

Comment: This is only applicable to the Prince library and the DocRaptor API service - standard browsers like Chrome don't support CSS Paged Media (the @page thing).